# Sample PHP script for listing and optionally deleting Twilio messages and associated media?

Tags: twilio-php

The following PHP example lists and optionally deletes SMS and MMS messages as well as associated media attachments.

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, "from" and "to" numbers are specified, and `$delete` is set to `false`.

```
$client = new Client($twilio_sid, $twilio_token);
$params = array(
    'from' => '+15555555555',
    'to'   => '+16666666666'
);
$delete = false;

$smsCounter = 0;
$mmsCounter = 0;
$mediaCounter = 0;

echo "<div style='font-family:monospace;'>";
foreach ($client->messages->read($params) as $message) {
    if (substr($message->sid, 0, 1) == "S") {
        $smsCounter++;
        echo "SMS #{$smsCounter} SID: {$message->sid} from {$message->from} to {$message->to}.<br>";
    }
    else {
        $mmsCounter++;
        echo "MMS #{$mmsCounter} SID: {$message->sid} from {$message->from} to {$message->to}.<br>";

        $allMedia = $client->messages($message->sid)->media->read();
        if (count($allMedia) > 0) {
            foreach ($allMedia as $media) {
                $mediaCounter++;
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Attachment SID: {$media->sid}.<br>";

                if ($delete) {
                    $media->delete($media->sid);
                }
            }  
        }
        else {
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No attachments found.<br>";
        }
    }

    if ($delete) {
        $message->delete($message->sid);
    }
}

echo "<br>{$smsCounter} SMS message" . ($smsCounter === 1 ? "" : "s") . " found" . ($delete ? "and deleted." : ".");
echo "<br>{$mmsCounter} multimedia message" . ($mmsCounter === 1 ? "" : "s") ." found" . ($delete ? "and deleted." : ".");
echo "<br>{$mediaCounter} media attachment" . ($mediaCounter === 1 ? "" : "s") ." found" . ($delete ? "and deleted." : ".");
```

To also delete the messages and associated media attachments, `$delete` can be set to `true`.

For a listing of all messages and media associated with the account, `$params` can be omitted from the first `foreach`, so that the line appears as follows:

```
foreach ($client->messages->read() as $message) {
```